# How to connect subreport to main report

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

Hi I have try to make a sub report using jasper but when I connect it, it can't show up when I preview, On every tutorial the example always connect to database or query, but in this case,  I want make report that connnect to database using java code so the connection will be in java not in the jasper. how can i do this?

this the sub report

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TargetSDSubReport" pageWidth="270" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="270" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="d736a7f6-85b9-4772-bd5a-2c325d35d2db">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
<parameter name="listGroup" class="java.util.List"/>
<field name="targetSD" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="targetSDDesc" class="java.lang.String"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="5" y="0" width="25" height="20" uuid="1a90696a-6d79-4eea-95b5-b95afc13c8de"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[No]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="30" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="1a90696a-6d79-4eea-95b5-b95afc13c8de"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[  Target SD]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="130" y="0" width="130" height="20" uuid="1a90696a-6d79-4eea-95b5-b95afc13c8de"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[  Deskripsi SD]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="5" y="0" width="25" height="20" uuid="e5302991-ecff-4b9b-80ad-915c3e85b822"/>
            <box rightPadding="2">
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="30" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="016a6929-6c92-4bf3-815f-027e1b0b84e2"/>
            <box leftPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{targetSD}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="130" y="0" width="130" height="20" uuid="016a6929-6c92-4bf3-815f-027e1b0b84e2"/>
            <box leftPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{targetSDDesc}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

I want to know, did I must set the parameter to this sub report ?? if yes, how to set it

this the main Report

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="PRPKReportPDF" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="58db78df-f84a-40cb-b718-7df30c5ec33a">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<parameter name="listGroup" class="java.util.List"/>
<field name="prpkNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="prpkTypeName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="createdDate" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="picPRPKName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="businessUnitName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="departmentName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="prpkDescription" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="prpkRequest" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="prpkBackground" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="prpkAnalysis" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="priorityName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="cost" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="targetSD" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="targetSDDesc" class="java.lang.String"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="36" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="6" width="555" height="30" uuid="7d980369-4787-4228-af9a-c3efb11e45ad"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[PEMBUATAN / REVISI PROGRAM KOMPUTER]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="14" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="182" y="-6" width="125" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[PRPK No.]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="274" y="-6" width="125" height="20" uuid="016a6929-6c92-4bf3-815f-027e1b0b84e2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{prpkNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="470" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="125" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Jenis PRPK]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="220" y="10" width="10" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="35" width="125" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Tanggal Dibuat]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="220" y="35" width="10" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="60" width="182" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Pihak yang membutuhkan]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="85" width="125" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Nama]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="220" y="85" width="10" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="110" width="182" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[OPU / Business Unit]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="220" y="110" width="10" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="135" width="182" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Divisi / Dept. / Lokasi]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="220" y="135" width="10" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="160" width="182" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Program yang diminta]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="220" y="160" width="10" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="220" width="182" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Uraian Permintaan *]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="220" y="220" width="10" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="280" width="182" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Latar Belakang]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="220" y="280" width="10" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="340" width="182" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Analisa Manfaat]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="220" y="340" width="10" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="400" width="182" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Tingkat Kepentingan]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="220" y="400" width="10" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="425" width="182" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Jumlah Investasi yang dibutuhkan]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="220" y="425" width="30" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[:  Rp.]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="450" width="200" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[SD / Information Technology Tujuan]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement x="230" y="10" width="260" height="20" uuid="016a6929-6c92-4bf3-815f-027e1b0b84e2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{prpkTypeName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="230" y="35" width="260" height="20" uuid="016a6929-6c92-4bf3-815f-027e1b0b84e2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{createdDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="230" y="85" width="260" height="20" uuid="016a6929-6c92-4bf3-815f-027e1b0b84e2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{picPRPKName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="230" y="110" width="260" height="20" uuid="016a6929-6c92-4bf3-815f-027e1b0b84e2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{businessUnitName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="230" y="135" width="260" height="20" uuid="016a6929-6c92-4bf3-815f-027e1b0b84e2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{departmentName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="230" y="160" width="260" height="60" uuid="016a6929-6c92-4bf3-815f-027e1b0b84e2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{prpkDescription}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="230" y="220" width="260" height="60" uuid="016a6929-6c92-4bf3-815f-027e1b0b84e2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{prpkRequest}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="230" y="280" width="260" height="60" uuid="016a6929-6c92-4bf3-815f-027e1b0b84e2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{prpkBackground}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="230" y="340" width="260" height="60" uuid="016a6929-6c92-4bf3-815f-027e1b0b84e2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{prpkAnalysis}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="230" y="400" width="260" height="20" uuid="016a6929-6c92-4bf3-815f-027e1b0b84e2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{priorityName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="250" y="425" width="240" height="20" uuid="016a6929-6c92-4bf3-815f-027e1b0b84e2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{cost}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="220" y="450" width="10" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
    <band height="100">
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="100" uuid="30fd3354-519f-4169-99fe-73879681bef2"/>
            <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{listGroup}]]></parametersMapExpression>
            <subreportParameter name="Target SD">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{targetSD}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="Target SD Description">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{targetSDDesc}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{listGroup})]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["TargetSDSubReport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band height="108" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="150" height="20" uuid="cb56e179-31af-405a-b6dc-c0477d9b959d"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Persetujuan ***]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="150" y="0" width="255" height="20" uuid="cb56e179-31af-405a-b6dc-c0477d9b959d"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Tanggapan dan Pandangan]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="405" y="0" width="150" height="20" uuid="cb56e179-31af-405a-b6dc-c0477d9b959d"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Pihak yang Membutuhkan **]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="20" width="150" height="60" uuid="cb56e179-31af-405a-b6dc-c0477d9b959d"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="150" y="20" width="127" height="60" uuid="cb56e179-31af-405a-b6dc-c0477d9b959d"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="277" y="20" width="128" height="60" uuid="cb56e179-31af-405a-b6dc-c0477d9b959d"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="405" y="20" width="150" height="60" uuid="cb56e179-31af-405a-b6dc-c0477d9b959d"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="80" width="150" height="20" uuid="cb56e179-31af-405a-b6dc-c0477d9b959d"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[CEO]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="150" y="80" width="127" height="20" uuid="cb56e179-31af-405a-b6dc-c0477d9b959d"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Senior Manager / EX Dir]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="277" y="80" width="128" height="20" uuid="cb56e179-31af-405a-b6dc-c0477d9b959d"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Jr. Manager / Manager]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="405" y="80" width="150" height="20" uuid="cb56e179-31af-405a-b6dc-c0477d9b959d"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Supervisor]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="80" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="40" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[*Rincian dari uraian permintaan dan juga tanggapan (counter) dari pihak Information Technology dapat disajikan di lembar lain, jika lembar ini tidak mencukupi.]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="555" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[** Setidaknya dengan tingkat Sr.Mgr.]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="60" width="555" height="20" uuid="d1375f2a-e5cc-40fc-8c58-fa669f8d3731"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[*** Disetujui oleh CEO, hanya jika ada jumlah (Rp.) investasi.]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
```

this main report if on sub report I must set the parameter, on this main report how to call the parameter of sub report and where i must to write it ??

Comment: For the subreport declaration in main, try to replace the `connectionExpression` with `dataSourceExpression`